# SBApplication (in this case SafariApplication) leads to SIGKILL (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, safari, applescript, scripting-bridge

I have a global SafariApplication variable (from a Scripting Bridge generated Safari header) that I set to, of course, the Safari Application:

```
self.safari = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
```

Then I check the URL of the current tab by doing:

```
SBElementArray *windows = [self.safari windows];
SafariWindow *window = [windows objectAtIndex:0];
SafariTab *tab = [window currentTab];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tab URL]];
```

This works fine.
I'm doing this twice a second, to get continuous information of what the user opens in Safari. 

But when I open a new tab in Safari, just sometimes (probably when the code is running at same time as I'm opening the new tab), it'll crash and give SIGKILL. Most of the time this occurs at the `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tab URL]];` 'line but it really depends.

I know, really weird, but I got no idea what's causing this.

I tried doing the same thing but then with AppleScript but this ended up the same.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance,

Erik van der Plas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! With some help I solved it: just `setTimeout:` on an SBApplication (in this case the SafariApplication) to a small time interval like 1 or 2 (seconds) and the code won't deadlock your program but just continue after 1 or 2 seconds of waiting.
In this case the method that is causing the deadlock will return nil.